# Applying padding to the head of table

Tags: html, css

Is there any way i can set padding to the thead alone of a table?

Answer (score 5):

```
table th
{
padding:15px;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to specify `table` in that selector, since `th` is necessarily a descendant of it.

Answer (score 4):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jhon</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>$200</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
    table, td, th { border : 1px solid black; }
    th { padding : 13px; }
    td { padding : 15px; }
</style>
```